# Java Program : Generate christmas tree : formatting?

Tags: java

So in my CS class, we have a little hw question and it isn't due for a week or so and it *almost* works except one little piece. Here is the assignment:

> Write a program named ChrisTree that produces images of Christmas trees as output. It should have a method with two parameters: one for the number of segments in the tree and one for the height of each segment. For example, the tree shown here on the left has three segments of height 4 and the one on the right has two segments of height 5.

[image: Image of two ASCII Christmas trees, with the left tree having three triangles, and the right having two triangles.]

So my code works except on some trees where the last line of the tree is and the trunk are both off by a space. I can't seem to plug up that hole without making a new one. Any one see a possible "root" of the issue? PS the tree segments and heights are variable by changing class constants (I know, its a terrible method of changing them, but thats what this guy wants)(I know its probably horribly redundant as well)

```
public class ChrisTree {
  public static final int SEGMENTS = 4;
  public static final int HEIGHT = 4;
  public static void main(String[] args){
  makeTree();
  }
  // makeTree: code that prints the tree; params: num. of segments of tree, height of tree segments
  public static void makeTree(){
  // maxStars: calculation the length of each line which is the sum of spaces and stars for any line
    int maxStars = 2*HEIGHT+2*SEGMENTS-3;
    // maxStr: master variable string that will be changed and printed for each line
    String maxStr = "";
    // populates maxStr will spaces; will be used with substring to generate needed spaces
    for (int len=0; len < maxStars; len++){
      maxStr+=" ";
    }
    // loops once per segment
    for (int i=1; i <= SEGMENTS; i++){
      // starStr: variable string that changes perline that holds the stars

      // populates starStr with stars
      // loops through each line
      for (int line=1; line <= HEIGHT; line++){
        String starStr = "";
        for (int j=1; j <= 2*line+2*i-3; j++){
          starStr+="*";
        }
        for (int space=0; space <= maxStars-(HEIGHT+line+i); space++){
          starStr = " " + starStr;
        }
        System.out.println(starStr);
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i <= maxStars/2;i++){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*\n");
    for (int i=0; i <= maxStars/2;i++){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*\n");
    for (int i=0; i <= maxStars/2-3;i++){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*******\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my defense of doing obvious homework problems, the solutions here just hurt my eyes too much.  (And I know these are standard homework problems, I did them back in the 80's, in Pascal).

```
package com.edwinbuck.christmas;

/**
 * Draws a ChristmasTree.

 * @author Edwin Buck
 */
public class ChristmasTree {

    public static final int SEGMENTS = 4;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSize = 1 + 2 * (SEGMENTS - 1) + 2 * (HEIGHT - 1);
        // for each segment beyond zero, we need 2 more asterisks.
        for (int segmentContrib = 0; segmentContrib < 2 * SEGMENTS; segmentContrib += 2) {
            // for each segment slice beyond zero, we need 2 more asterisks.
            for (int sliceContrib = 0; sliceContrib < 2 * HEIGHT; sliceContrib += 2) {
                drawCentered(maxSize, 1 + segmentContrib + sliceContrib);
            }
        }
        // draw the trunk
        drawCentered(maxSize, 1);
        drawCentered(maxSize, 1);
        // draw the base
        drawCentered(maxSize, 7);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a line of asterisks, centered within size spaces.
     *
     * @param size The size to center on.
     * @param asterisks The number of asterisks to draw.
     */
    private static void drawCentered(int size, int asterisks) {
        int before = (size - asterisks) / 2;
        int after = size - before - asterisks;
        print(before, " ");
        print(asterisks, "*");
        print(after, " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Draws a character a number of times.
     *
     * @param count The number of time to draw the character.
     * @param character The character to draw.
     */
    private static void print(int count, final String character) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
    }

}
```

The key is to realize that all of the lines are centered asterisks of variable size.  Once you do that, then you only need to figure out the loop to draw the sections (and the maximum line size).

The maximum line size is controlled by the bottom most section.  Each input (`SEGMENTS` and `HEIGHT`) needs to be converted from "count from 1" to "count from 0".  Each additional segment adds two to the asterisk size, as does each additional slice.  The tree must have at least one asterisk, the one (trunk) running down the center.  This leads to the formula

```
 1 + 2*(SEGMENTS-1) + 2(HEIGHT-1)
```

which many have simplified to

```
 2*SEGMENTS + 2*HEIGHT - 3
```

I didn't simplify it because it hides *intent*, something that's hard to recover in code once lost.

Then while walking through the loops, I decided to have the contributors to the size increment by two.  It makes the rest of the math easier as we don't have to put "magic" formulas and math in odd places.  This means that we can reuse our `drawCentered(...)` with the parameter `1 + segmentContrib + sliceContrib` where the two other variables are the segment and slice "asterisk" contributions.

Finally, we draw a trunk of two vertical asterisks and the base.

Comment: My only consolation in doing this is so people can see what a solution could look like.  This early on in one's programming ability, most of the solutions one will encounter will look pretty rough (like the others posted here).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is extremely late, but I just wrote this and it worked.

```
public class ChrisTree {
    public static final int SEGMENTS = 4;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makeTree();
    }

    public static void makeTree() {
        int maxStars = 2 * HEIGHT + 2 * SEGMENTS - 3;
        String maxStr = "";
        for (int l = 0; l < maxStars; l++) {
            maxStr += " ";
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= SEGMENTS; i++) {
            for (int line = 1; line <= HEIGHT; line++) {
                String starStr = "";
                for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * line + 2 * i - 3; j++) {
                    starStr += "*";
                }
                for (int space = 0; space <= maxStars - (HEIGHT + line + i); space++) {
                    starStr = " " + starStr;
                }
                System.out.println(starStr);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxStars / 2; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" " + "*" + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxStars / 2; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" " + "*" + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxStars / 2 - 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" " + "*******");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain *why* it works?  Right now it's just a bunch of code that accomplishes some goal, but that's not very helpful to those that want to figure out what was wrong with the original code.